# Simple limit calculation $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n(n + 1)}/(n+1)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Why is this limit equals 1?

$$\eqalign{
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {{\sqrt n \cdot\sqrt {n + 1} } \over {n + 1}} = 1  \cr 
  &  \cr} $$

I tried dividing by n, but it gives 0/0, which isn't so great..

Comment: It should give $1/1$, not $0/0$.

Comment: Can you demonstrate please?

Comment: See DonAntonio's answer below.

Comment: Replace n+1 with n (for big n the difference is negligible). Simplify. What do you think?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt n\sqrt{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{\sqrt1\sqrt{1+\frac1n}}{1+\frac1n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{1\cdot 1}1=1$$

Comment: When you divide sqrt(n) by n, shouldn't it be sqrt(n/n^2)?

Comment: I divided by $\;n\;$ both numerator and denominator, **not** by $\;\sqrt n\;$ .

Comment: This was my thougt, because you divide a square of n, and not n

$$\eqalign{
  & {{\sqrt {{n \over {{n^2}}}} *\sqrt {{n \over {{n^2}}} + {1 \over {{n^2}}}} } \over {{n \over n} + {1 \over n}}}  \cr 
  &   \cr 
  &  \cr} $$

Comment: What you show is incorrect algebraically. I repeat: I divided by $\;n\;$ . 

Taking into account that $\;\frac1n=\frac1{\sqrt n}\frac1{\sqrt n}\;$ , we get: $$\frac{\frac1{\sqrt n}\sqrt n\frac1{\sqrt n}\sqrt{n+1}}{\frac1n(n+1)}=\frac{\sqrt 1\sqrt{1+\frac1n}}{1+\frac1n}\ldots$$

Comment: @DonAntonio why does the thing which CaptainDragon has showed above your comment is incorrect algebraically? I really don't understand.

Comment: @KiberPrestupnik: CaptainDragon divided both terms in the product by $n$. That's equivalent to dividing the product by $n^2$.

Answer (score 10):

$$\frac{\sqrt n\sqrt{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1}}=\left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^{-1/2}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1^{-1/2}=1$$

Answer (score 7):

$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}} \\
=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n(1/n+1)}} \\
\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1/n+1}} = 1
$$

Answer (score 1):

As usual, the asymptotic notation yields the same results in a more powerful way[0] without any calculations (i don't know why it isn't more used)

$\frac{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}}{n+1}$; since $\sqrt{n^2 + 1} \sim_{\infty} \sqrt{n^2} \sim_{\infty} n$, and $n + 1 \sim_{\infty} n$, then by substituting you get $\frac{n}{n} = 1$

[0] I mean a more powerful way because it can easily be extended; something like $\sqrt{\sqrt{n} + n} \sim_{\infty} \sqrt{n}$, which is so much easier to manipulate